# How to get data on magento model based on phone number?

Tags: mysql, magento, orm, model, updatemodel

> I want to edit magento custom table based upon phone number and status
>   search, i am not sure how to do it this in magento model architecture.
>   Please help me. I found some update queries with load id but i want to
>   load data using customer phone number, and then do an data update.

```
$phone="12345678";
    $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('phone', $phone);
            //return $collection->getFirstItem();
            $id = $collection->getFirstItem();
            $u_id = $id["entity_id"];
```

Comment: Please upload some code which you are using.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/magento-custom-non-eav-model-load-by-multiple-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$existingUser = Mage::getModel("supportticket/supportticketadminusersession")->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('user_phnumber', $user["phone_number"]);
$existingId = $existingUser->getFirstItem()->getId();
$data = array(
                    'customer_phnumber' => "",
                    'user_status' => 0,
                    'created_time' => $date,
                    'updated_time' => ""
                    );
                $updateCollection = Mage::getModel("supportticket/supportticketadminusersession")->load($existingId)->addData($data);
$updateCollection->save();
```